# How to implement Region of Interest Pooling layer in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create Faster RCNN like model. I get stuck when it comes to the ROI pooling from the feature map. I know here billinear sampling can be used but, it may not help for end to end training. How to implement this ROI pooling layer in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

Bilinear sampling - as the name suggests - can actually be used even with end-to-end training as it's basically a linear operation. However, the disadvantage would be that your local maxima (i.e. strong excitations or certain units) could vanish because your sampling points just happen to be close to the minima. To remedy this, you can instead apply a `max_pool(features, kernel, stride)` operation where kernel and stride are adjusted such that the final output of this max pool operation does always have the same dimensions.

An example: your features have size `12x12` and you would like to pool to `4x4`, then setting `kernel=(3,3)` and `stride=(3,3)` would help you achieve that and for each `3x3` patch, the strongest excitations in the respective feature maps will be contained in the output.